# output only with same id

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT   id,
         account_id,
         move_id
FROM     account_move_line 
WHERE    account_id IN
         (SELECT account_id
          FROM account_move_line 
          GROUP BY account_id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) 
AND      account_id = 1974
```

Data output is :

```
______________________________
|id      |account_id |move_id
| 41623  |    1974   |  8865
| 41624  |    1974   |  8865
| 45229  |    1974   |  9289
| 1208   |    1974   |  104
| 39628  |    1974   |  8168
| 39629  |    1974   |  8168
```

As you can see in line one and two, `move_id` is the same. 
 In the last two lines of output again `move_id` is the same. 
 How can I update my query that output would be only if `move_id` is the same? 
 So basically there shouldn't be lines with ids 45229 and 1208.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: @mkRabbani postgresql 10

Comment: what will be the outcome if move_id=8865 contain same id two times like | 41623  |    1974   |  8865,| 41623  |    1974   |  8865 @Chaban33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a correlated subquery

```
select id, account_id , move_id
from account_move_line a
where exists (select 1 from account_move_line b where a.move_id=b.move_id
                     group by b.account_id
                     having count(distinct id) > 1 and account_id = 1974) 
  and account_id = 1974
```

Comment: having this error ERROR:  column "b.account_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use MOV ID instead of account_id as below-

```
SELECT 
id, 
account_id , 
move_id 
FROM account_move_line 
WHERE move_ID in 
(
    SELECT move_ID
    FROM account_move_line 
    GROUP BY move_ID 
    HAVING COUNT(move_ID) > 1
) 
AND account_id = 1974
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simply using `exists` rather than using aggregation in a subquery -- if yo care at all about performance.

So:

```
SELECT aml.id, aml.account_id, aml.move_id
FROM account_move_line aml
WHERE aml.account_id = 1974 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM account_move_line aml2
              WHERE aml2.account_id = aml.account_id AND
                    aml2.move_id = aml.move_id AND
                    aml2.id <> aml.id
             );
```